# Access native KafkaConsumer in Camel RoutePolicy to change polling behaviour

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I "monitor" the number of consecutive failures in my Camel processing pipeline with a [Camel RoutePolicy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/route-policy.html).

When a threshold of failures is reached, I want to pause the processing for a configured amount of time because it probably means that the data from another system is not yet ready and therefore every message fails.

Since the source of my pipeline is a **Kafka topic**, I should not just stop the whole route because the **broker would assume my consumer died** and rebalance.

The best way to "pause" topic consumption seems to be to [pause](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause-java.util.Collection-) the `[KafkaConsumer][3]` (the native, not the one of Camel). Like this, the consumer **continues to poll** the broker, but it **does not fetch any messages**. Exactly what I need.

But can I access the native `[KafkaConsumer][3]` from the RoutePolicy context to call the `pause` and `resume` methods?

The [spring-kafka listener containers expose these methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.14.RELEASE/reference/html/#pause-resume), it would be nice to use them from Camel too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported, the two methods must be added to the camel-kafka consumer first.

There is also an existing issue for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15106